# how create a new calculated field with increment count

Tags: tableau-api

I would like to create a new **calculated field** (a new column in my dataset) that would count and increment every time an ID from another column appears.

I was able to achieve the results using excel (see image)

[check here the example achieved with excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBTO6.png)

this is the formula used in excel I used to get the result I intend to achieve in tableau:

```
=COUNTIF($A$2:A3,A3)
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a couple of way to do that in that and they all rely on Table Calculation Function.

In your case Index(), Rank() or Dense_Rank() will probably be the answer.

Here is tableau article on how to use it :

[Table Calculation Functions](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/functions_functions_tablecalculation.htm)